# lambda Expresion also sorted function

Tags: python-3.x

Here I dont understand the program flow. anyone explain me what happening?
the down written program is my program

My code here

d={'a':2,'b':4,'d':5,'c':3}

x=sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[1])

print(x)

Answer (score 0):

```
d={'a':2,'b':4,'d':5,'c':3}
# defines a dictionary

x=sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[1])
```

- d.items(): returns a list with all dictionary keys and values
- the parameter key: the function used to sort
- lambda x:x[1]: mini function to determine the value used to sort, in this case the number (second index)
- sorted() returns a new sorted list